# How to take average of 2nd column values/counts based on first column elements/genes between different dataframes/patients in Python, R?

Tags: python, r, pandas, merge

Input dataframes:

**df1:**

[image: Genes with the count of sample 1]

**df2:**

[image: Genes with the count of sample 2]

Output should be a data frame with all possible genes in df1 and df2 with average. If df1 have an element which is not in df2 then count that element as zero in df2. Resulted dataframe should be like this.
resulted dataframe:

[image: All genes in both patients with average]

[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnEQq.png): [image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One option in `R` is to bind the two datasets together after expanding the two datasets with `complete`, grouped by 'Genes', `summarise` the `mean` of 'Count' column

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
out <- bind_rows(df1, df2, .id = 'grp') %>% 
         complete(grp, Genes, fill = list(Count = 0)) %>%
         group_by(Genes) %>% 
         summarise(Average = mean(Count))
# A tibble: 5 x 2
#  Genes Average
#  <chr>   <dbl>
#1 A           9
#2 B           7
#3 C          11
#4 D          13
#5 E           5
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Genes = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), Count = c(10, 14, 
4, 20)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

df2 <- structure(list(Genes = c("A", "C", "D", "E"), Count = c(8, 18, 
6, 10)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. But B value should be 7 and E value should be 5 instead of 14 and 10.

Comment: @JaleesUrRahman  for `Gene` A, your average is showed as 14 in expected, but the values in both datasets are 8 and 10.  Not clear though.  Same issue in 'D' as well (20, 6 -> average 13)

Comment: Yeah I have done this mistake. Your answer is exactly what I wanted. Thanks! How to store the resulted dataframe?